# Iterate over all lists with one duplicate

Tags: python

Consider all lists of length `n` where the values are integers from the `range 0 to n-1`. I would like to iterate as quickly as possible over every possible such list that has exactly one duplicate. If `n = 2` then the possible lists are:

```
00
11
```

If `n = 3` they are:

```
001
002
110
112
220
221
100
200
011
211
022
122
010
020
101
121
202
212
```

The total number of such lists is `n! * (n choose 2)` so I would like to avoid storing them all in memory if at all possible.

For each list I want to call a function that calculates a function of the list.
What's a good way to do this?

**Benchmarks** On my computer I get the following benchmark results

```
timeit all(one_duplicate(6))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.87 ms per loops
timeit all(one_duplicate(7))
10 loops, best of 3: 59 ms per loop
timeit all(one_duplicate(8))
1 loops, best of 3: 690 ms per loop
timeit all(one_duplicate(9))
1 loops, best of 3: 7.58 s per loop
```

and

```
timeit all(duplicates(range(6)))
10 loops, best of 3: 22.8 ms per loop
timeit all(duplicates(range(7)))
1 loops, best of 3: 416 ms per loop    
timeit all(duplicates(range(8)))
1 loops, best of 3: 9.78 s per loop
```

and

```
timeit all(all_doublet_tuples(6))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.36 ms per loop
timeit all(all_doublet_tuples(7))
10 loops, best of 3: 60 ms per loop
timeit all(all_doublet_tuples(8))
1 loops, best of 3: 542 ms per loop
timeit all(all_doublet_tuples(9))
1 loops, best of 3: 7.27 s per loop
```

I declare `all_doublet_tuples` and `one_duplicate` to be equal first at the moment (allowing for noise in the tests).

Comment: The total number of possible lists is actually `n! * (n choose 2)`.

Comment: @interjay Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of **any** of the desired output tuples in this way: It was derived by duplicating the first (lets say from the left) doublet elem and inserting it at the position of the second doublet.

Therefore my solution is basically this two-step process:

1. generate all `n-1` permutations of `range(n)`
2. for each tuple from 1.:
   take each single element and insert it at each position **ahead** (to avoid duplicates) including at the very end

---

```
import itertools as it

# add_doublet accomplishes step 2
def add_doublet(t):
    for i in range(len(t)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(t)+1):
            yield t[:j] + (t[i],) + t[j:]


def all_doublet_tuples(n):
    for unique_tuple in it.permutations(range(n), n-1):
        for doublet_tuple in add_doublet(unique_tuple):
            yield doublet_tuple



from pprint import pprint

n = 3
pprint(list(all_doublet_tuples(n)))
```

I do not print the output here cause its kind of lenghty ... and the case for n=3 is boring.

Comment: Thanks. You are equal first :)

Comment: I just noticed that your memory usage is much lower than the alternatives given.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

def one_duplicate(n):
    nrange = list(range(n))
    for x in nrange:
        without_x = nrange[:x] + nrange[x+1:]
        for i, j in itertools.combinations(nrange, 2):
            for others in map(list, itertools.permutations(without_x, n-2)):
                others.insert(i, x)
                others.insert(j, x)
                yield others

>>> list(one_duplicate(2))
[[0, 0], [1, 1]]
>>> list(one_duplicate(3))
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 2], [1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 2], [0, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2]]
>>> list(one_duplicate(4))
[[0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1, 3], [0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 2, 3], [0, 0, 3, 1], [0, 0, 3, 2], [0, 1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0, 3], [0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 3], [0, 3, 0, 1], [0, 3, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 3, 0], [0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 3, 0], [0, 3, 1, 0], [0, 3, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0, 3], [2, 0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0, 3], [3, 0, 0, 1], [3, 0, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 3, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 3, 0], [3, 0, 1, 0], [3, 0, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 3, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0, 0], [2, 3, 0, 0], [3, 1, 0, 0], [3, 2, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0, 3], [1, 1, 2, 0], [1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 3, 0], [1, 1, 3, 2], [1, 0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 1, 0], [1, 3, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 3, 1], [1, 2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 3, 0, 1], [1, 3, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 1], [0, 1, 3, 1], [2, 1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 3, 1], [3, 1, 0, 1], [3, 1, 2, 1], [0, 2, 1, 1], [0, 3, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1, 1], [2, 3, 1, 1], [3, 0, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0, 1], [2, 2, 0, 3], [2, 2, 1, 0], [2, 2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3, 0], [2, 2, 3, 1], [2, 0, 2, 1], [2, 0, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 2, 0], [2, 3, 2, 1], [2, 0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 3, 2], [2, 1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 0, 2], [2, 3, 1, 2], [0, 2, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 0], [1, 2, 2, 3], [3, 2, 2, 0], [3, 2, 2, 1], [0, 2, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 0, 2], [1, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 0, 2], [3, 2, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 2], [0, 3, 2, 2], [1, 0, 2, 2], [1, 3, 2, 2], [3, 0, 2, 2], [3, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 0, 1], [3, 3, 0, 2], [3, 3, 1, 0], [3, 3, 1, 2], [3, 3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 2, 1], [3, 0, 3, 1], [3, 0, 3, 2], [3, 1, 3, 0], [3, 1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 3, 0], [3, 2, 3, 1], [3, 0, 1, 3], [3, 0, 2, 3], [3, 1, 0, 3], [3, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 0, 3], [3, 2, 1, 3], [0, 3, 3, 1], [0, 3, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3, 0], [1, 3, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3, 0], [2, 3, 3, 1], [0, 3, 1, 3], [0, 3, 2, 3], [1, 3, 0, 3], [1, 3, 2, 3], [2, 3, 0, 3], [2, 3, 1, 3], [0, 1, 3, 3], [0, 2, 3, 3], [1, 0, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 0, 3, 3], [2, 1, 3, 3]]
```

Here is a description of the algorithm:

- Find all the index pairs using `itertools.combinations(nrange, 2)`
- For each number `x` in the range, get all permutations of length `n-2` for the entire range except for `x`
- In each of these permutations, insert `x` at each of the indices found in the first step and yield the result.

Timing comparisons between my answer and [Peter Stahl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14861951/505154):

```
# Just showing they both get the same result
In [23]: set(peter(range(6))) == set(tuple(x) for x in fj(6))
Out[23]: True

In [24]: %timeit list(peter(range(6)))
10 loops, best of 3: 27.3 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit list(fj(6))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.32 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit list(peter(range(7)))
1 loops, best of 3: 506 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit list(fj(7))
10 loops, best of 3: 81 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks but this suffers from a fatal problem. Try this ... for list in list(one_duplicate(10)):   print sum(list),  . You never get any output at all.  Would just making it a generator solve this?

Comment: @Majid - It is a generator, I only used `list(one_duplicate(n))` to show the output.  Also, using `list` as a variable name is confusing, for your loop you would use `for lst in one_duplicate(10): print sum(lst)`

Comment: There's no need for `list(range(n))`, at least not in Python 2. Apart from that, +1.

Comment: Interesting, but is this increase in performance really necessary? You nearly never need to convert a generator to a list for most purposes and operations. Besides that, your code is horribly complicated.

Comment: The conversion to a list is just to show the output, unless you are referring to `list(range(n))` which is so the code works on Python 3 as well.

Comment: @F.J I don't quite understand why your method is faster than mine. Both generators from your method and mine contain the same numbers of elements. By converting them to a list, they should be equally performant. Can you explain that to me please?

Comment: @F.J Your lovely code spends almost all of its time doing the insert according to a simple profile. Can this be avoided?

Comment: @PeterStahl Your method throws away `n^n - n! * (n choose 2)` lists. That is a number that becomes huge very quickly.

Comment: @PeterStahl For `n=10` it throws away `9836704000` lists for example.

Comment: @Majid Alright, I understand. :) Thanks. But as I said, if you don't need to convert the generator to a list, is performance then so important?

Comment: @PeterStahl It is as I will be performing a function on each list and so I would like the list generation overhead to be as small as possible.  Of course now I need to optimise the function too but that's a different question :)

Comment: @Majid I tried changing the code to avoid the insert but it was slower.

Comment: @F.J Oh.. what is the memory usage of `for others in map(list, itertools.permutations(without_x, n-2))` ? It seems worryingly high. Is there anything that can be done about that?

Comment: @Majid - sure, Python 3 won't have that memory issue, but here are a few options for Python 2.x: use `itertools.imap` instead of `map`, change it to `for others in (list(perm) for perm in itertools.permutations(without_x, n-2)):`, or just use `for others in itertools.permutations(without_x, n-2):` and just inside that for loop do `others = list(others)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
n=3
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-i-1):
        for perm in map(list, itertools.permutations(range(n), n-1)):
            perm.insert(i, perm[i+j])
            print perm
```

key concept here is to generate all N-1 length permutations from a N-length set and then just run it over all repetition combinations (i and i+j)

In case of N=3, permutations are:

> (0, 1) (0, 2) (1, 0) (1, 2) (2, 0) (2, 1)

and repeated elements can be at positions marked by X:

> XX_, X_X, _XX

Your results is the 'multiplication' of those sets:

```
        XX_  X_X  _XX
(0, 1)  001  010  011
(0, 2)  002  020  022
(1, 0)  110  101  100
(1, 2)  112  121  122
(2, 0)  220  202  200
(2, 1)  221  212  211
```

Everything is computed on the fly. I guess memory consumption is O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are about how to do so without creating an actual `list` in memory, and how to run a function on each one, so I'll answer that part generically first, then for your specific problem.

> The total number of possible lists is n*(n-1) * (n choose 2) so I would like to avoid storing them all in memory if at all possible.

You just need to create a generator function, which `yield`s answers one by one, instead of a regular function that appends each answer to a `list` and then returns that `list`.

> For each list I want to call a function that calculates a function of the list.
>   What's a good way to do this?

You can call a generator function's and use the result as an iterator. For example:

```
for element in my_generator_function(n):
    my_function(element)
```

If you want the results of calling `my_function` on each element, you can build another generator function:

```
def apply_to(my_function, my_iterator):
    for element in my_iterator):
        yield my_function(element)
```

However, there's already a built-in function that does exactly that, called `map` in Python 3, or `itertools.imap` in Python 2.

Or, even more simply, you can use a generator expression:

```
results = (my_function(element) for element in my_generator_function(n))
```

For more, see the [Iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators), [Generators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators), and [Generator Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) section in the official Python tutorial.

Now, you can break your problem down like this:

- For each number in the set of the first n numbers:

  - All permutations of that number twice, together with n-2 of the other numbers

For n=2, this means all permutations of (0, 0) together with 0 numbers from (1), and all permutations of (1, 1) together with 0 numbers from (0). For n=3, you've got all permutations of (0, 0) together with 1 of the numbers (1, 2), and all permutations of (1, 1) together with 1 of the numbers (0, 2), and all permutations of (2, 2) together with 1 of the numbers (0, 1). And so on.

So, translating that directly to Python, using the magic of [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
def one_duplicate_element(n):
    for i in range(n):
        rest = (j for j in range(n) if j != i)
        for combination in itertools.combinations(rest, n-2):
            yield from itertools.permutations(combination + (i, i))
```

This uses the `yield from` statement in Python 3.3, which means "yield every element from this iterator". If you're using 3.2 or earlier, you need to do that explicitly with a loop:

```
def one_duplicate_element(n):
    for i in range(n):
        rest = (j for j in range(n) if j != i)
        for combination in itertools.combinations(rest, n-2):
            for permutation in itertools.permutations(combination + (i, i)):
                yield permutation
```

But you'll notice that, while this does exactly what you asked for, it doesn't generate the same list as your sample output. Even ignoring ordering (which I don't think is relevant for you), there are duplicates. Why?

Well, what are the permutations of the set `(0, 0)`? That's a trick question; `(0, 0)` can't be a set, because it has duplicates in it. So, whatever `(0, 0)` is, what are its permutations? Well, by the usual definition of permutations on ordered tuples, what would be `((0, 0), (0, 0))`. And that's exactly what `itertools.permutations` gives you.

You can look at how `permutations` works and write a `permutations_without_duplicates` function yourself, or you can use the `unique_everseen` function in the [Recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) section of the docs, or you can sort the results and use the `unique_justseen`, or… Well, let's pick one:

```
def one_duplicate_element_no_duplicates(n):
    yield from unique_everseen(one_duplicate_element(n))
```

Comment: Thanks but actually I don't know how to generate the list in any elegant way.

Comment: @Majid: OK, I'll edit my answer. Obviously that's going to make it even more verbose…

Comment: This gives each combination twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product    

def duplicates(r):
    r_len = len(r)
    dup_len = r_len - 1
    for tup in product(r, repeat=r_len):
        if len(set(tup)) == dup_len:
            yield tup

>>> list(duplicates(range(2)))
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]

>>> list(duplicates(range(3)))
[(0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 2),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (0, 2, 0),
 (0, 2, 2),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (2, 0, 0),
 (2, 0, 2),
 (2, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 2, 0),
 (2, 2, 1)]
```

Some benchmarks on my machine:

```
%timeit all(duplicates(range(5)))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.5 ms per loop

%timeit all(duplicates(range(6)))
10 loops, best of 3: 38.6 ms per loop

%timeit all(duplicates(range(7)))
1 loops, best of 3: 766 ms per loop

%timeit all(duplicates(range(8)))
1 loops, best of 3: 18.8 s per loop
```

Comment: That's neat! However, I need it to be as fast as possible so I suppose this is going to a waste a lot of time discarding lists that don't have duplicates.

Comment: @Majid I don't know whether this is the fastest solution possible but since `itertools.product` uses a generator, it is very fast and memory-efficient.

Comment: @Majid I think you should profile before making such statements. Often in CPython doing some extra iteration at the C-level produces better results than a pure-python solution(meaning no usage of modules written in C, like `itertools`).

Comment: OK thanks. I see the question is being downvoted a lot too now!

Comment: @Majid Look at my measurements. My method is really fast even for large ranges. I'm sure this is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: The benchmark is flawed; it measures the time it takes to build `range(n)` and set up a generator. A fair benchmark would be `%timeit all(duplicates(range(10000)))`. That, however, would not complete before the heat death of the universe because it has to generate 10000^10000 elements.

Comment: @larsmans Are the benchmarks I have added to the question fair?

Comment: @Majid Do you really need to convert the generator to a list? You nearly never need to do this for most operations. What do you want to do with the results?

Comment: @Majid No. I need to call a function for every list that computes some property of it.